# how to match items between 2 different lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have 2 different lists:

```
['2', '1']
['equals', 'x']
```

I want to match the items so 2 = "equals" and 1 = "x" in order to recreate the original sentence "x equals x", also i have a third list which is:

```
['1', '2', '1']
```

I need the third list to recreate the original sentence since it has all the positions, to do this I thought of making the numbers equal to the words such as 1 = "x" and printing the list of numbers in order to have the full sentence. The problem is i do not know how to make the numbers equal to the words. Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: What have you tried already? can you show your own code and explain exactly what is not working to your expectation? Please read how to put together a [mcve] for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary might be what you need here which maps keys to values. You can create a dictionary from the first two lists by zipping them. And with this dictionary, it should be fairly straight forward to map any list of numbers to words:

```
mapping = dict(zip(['2', '1'], ['equals', 'x']))

mapping
# {'1': 'x', '2': 'equals'}

[mapping.get(num) for num in ['1', '2', '1']]
# ['x', 'equals', 'x']
```

To make the list a sentence, use `join` method:

```
" ".join(mapping.get(num) for num in ['1', '2', '1'])
# 'x equals x'
```